# Can I directly pass string parameter to Quicksight function as argument?

Tags: amazon-web-services, parameters, arguments, amazon-quicksight

I made a parameter with a custom list of options 'MM', 'YYYY', and 'Q'. When a user selects one, I planned my calculated field to use it as an argument for the extract() function, like this:

```
extract(${period}, date)
```

I tried to omit the quotes, include them, but nothing works, saying "At least one of the arguments in this function does not have correct type."

Is what I want to make possible?

Answer (score 0):

From the little testing I've done it looks like `extract` requires a string literal as its first argument. This could be a bug and may be worth bringing to Amazon's attention.

As a workaround, you could solve this by using `ifelse`

```
ifelse(
  ${period} = 'MM', extract('MM', {Date}),
  ${period} = 'YYYY', extract('YYYY', {Date}),
  extract('Q', {Date})
)
```

This is actually kind of nice because it gives you the opportunity to make the filter control more readable (e.g. `Month`, `Year`, `Quarter`) then do

```
ifelse(
  ${period} = 'Month', extract('MM', {Date}),
  ${period} = 'Year', extract('YYYY', {Date}),
  extract('Q', {Date})
)
```

This works for your example because your grouping options are well defined, however, it wouldn't work for a dynamic, less understood set of controls.